# fs.readdirSync(__dirname) showing .js file extension instead of .ts

Tags: typescript, node.js-fs

I have the following code:

```
console.log(fs.readdirSync(__dirname));
```

Which prints out the following:

```
[ 'index.js', 'objective.js', 'quest.js', 'user_objective.js' ]
```

However, my file directory setup is as follows:

[image]

Why would it think the .ts extension is .js?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   
    "target": "es6",
  
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "rootDir": "./src" /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */,
    "outDir": "./dist" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
   
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js doesn't support TypeScript.

Your TypeScript is compiled into JavaScript and stored in `.js` files (`"outDir": "./dist" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,`).

Node.js runs the resulting JavaScript.

The `__dirname` for the JS files contains JS files.

Comment: So is the solution to set the `allowJs` flag to true? I did that, and I get new errors. Want to make sure I am going down the right path.

Comment: The solution to what? There's no problem.

Comment: I changed my code to accept .js instead of the .ts extension *shrug*